# jquery event on a php view

Tags: php, jquery

I have created a php generated by a loop with php. That basically loads all the posts from my db.
On the html template used by the view I added some jquery to show an hidden element(to update the comments on the posts loaded) and that works but as I selected a class in my jquery event, when I click it show all the hidden elements having the same class... which is normal, but I'm trying to add dynamically an number so that I can point to this attribute when I click...
Here is my view - I have put in bold the elements that I :

```
<?php ob_start();?>
<?php $titlecomment = 'Comments :'; ?>
<?php foreach ($com as $c): ?>
    <?php $idcomment = $c->getIdComment()?>
    <?php $id = (int)$_GET['id'] ?>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
        <form method ="POST" action="<?="../Controler/commentDelOrUpdate.php?idcomment=".$idcomment."&id=".$id;?>">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-6">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-2"><?= $c->getDate()?></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-2"><?= $c->getName()?></div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3"><?= $c->getComment()?></div>
                    <div>
                        <div type="button" class="col-sm-0.5 btn btn-primary editField" name="edit">Edit</div>
                        <button type="submit" class="col-sm-0.5 btn btn-primary" name="delete">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    **<textarea rows="2" class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-3 hiddenField" style="display: none; color: black;" name="newcomment"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-1 btn btn-primary hiddenField" style="display: none" name="update">Update</button>**
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php $comment = ob_get_clean();?>

And here is my jQuery:

<script>
        $(function () {
            //add number to class hiddenField
            //increment that class
            //event on click to the selected class

            $(".editField").on('click',function () {
                $('.hiddenField').toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting *all* `.hiddenField` elements, you can use DOM navigation functions to find specifically the ones near the element being clicked.  Basically navigate up to the closest common parent element and then find the `.hiddenField` elements within that parent.  Something like this:

```
$(".editField").on('click',function () {
    $(this).closest('div.row').find('.hiddenField').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks David!